# How to split a image without using canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How do I cut up a image without using the canvas? Lets say I create a image the regular way with `new Image()` but how do get parts of it without using `canvas.getImageData` since I want this to work while offline in chrome. I making a small game and I have a spritesheet which I have to cut up and I want this game to work locally, but chrome gets that cross platform error. Is there any other way that I can get parts of the image?
If this is a bad question please dont -rep me, just say so and I'll remove it

**Also, am talking about game sprites not css sprites**

Comment: No, this is for a html5 game using canvas, but I want a method to cut up the sprite sheet without using the canvas to allow it to work offline/locally on chrome. Also by sprite I mean game sprite not css sprite

Comment: You can use [`drawImage()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) method and clip the image.

Comment: :( I was hoping that there was someother method since thats not very efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having CORS security violations when running offline?

Otherwise, html canvas works fine offline, too :-)

As long as you have access to the spritesheet you can cut it up locally.

If your individual sprites are rectangular, you can use the extended version of drawImage instead of the more involved getImageData

```
canvas.width=characterWidth    // resize the canvas to the character width 
canvas.height=characterHeight  // resize the canvas to the character height

context.drawImage(
    spritesheet,                      // the spritesheet image
    characterX,characterY,            // the top-left x/y of the character on the spritesheet
    characterWidth,characterHeight,   // the width/height of the character on the spritesheet
    0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)   // draw the character on the canvas
```

Then you can do canvas.toDataURL to "cut" that character out and use the dataurl to create an html image object.

**[ Addition: use crossOrigin flag to satisfy CORS requirements ]**

To satisfy CORS restrictions, you can use the crossOrigin="anonymous" flag on either your html img element or when creating a javascript image object.

Important: Your server must also be configured to deliver images in a CORS compliant way:

http://enable-cors.org/

Here's an example of using to crossOrigin flag to download an image that doesn't taint an html canvas:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/K9C42/

```
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/flags.jpg";
    function start(){
        canvas.width=100;
        canvas.height=100;
        ctx.drawImage(img,125,10,100,100,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var img1=new Image();
        img1.onload=function(){
            document.body.appendChild(img1);
        }
        img1.src=canvas.toDataURL();
    }
```

Comment: Yea am havign CORS problems but the method uses toDataURL

Comment: Not to worry! Canvas does "all that work" once at the beginning of the app.  Canvas has more than enough horsepower to handle quickly cutting up even huge spritesheets--that's its strong suite!  As to CORS,  how are you delivering your app?  I ask because CORS issues can be overcome by delivering your spritesheet with the crossOrigin="anonymous" flag and then saving the spritesheet to the same folder where you deliver the html,css,js.

Comment: What magic do you speak of crossOrigin="anonymous" flag and how would I be able to use it? Because if I can get rid of the CORS problem, am good to go, since I have a optimized method to slice images but it uses toDataURL()

Comment: Alternatively you could simply deliver all your characters as separate pre-cut images.

Comment: crossOrigin="anonymous" tells the browser to try to mark this image as not cross-domain even if it's actually being downloaded from another domain.  Then the canvas will not be "tainted" and you can use toDataURL.  **Important:** the site delivering the spritesheet must be configured also.  Dropbox.com is a public file hosting site that allows CORS compliant downloads from it's public folder. I'll update my answer with an example shortly.

Comment: Thanks, but your idea about separate pre cut images would be fine if it werent javascript since than I have to deal with mutiple `onload` for each image